# Adding AND in a WHERE clause using ViewBag and SelectList with LINQ in Controller (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, viewbag

How do I add a 2nd `WHERE` clause ('AND') in my current `ViewBag` with `LINQ` in `Controller`? Thanks!

```
ViewBag.Subjects = new SelectList(_odb.SUBJ_MSTR.
                   Where(o => o.TYPE== "4").OrderBy(o => o.SUBJ_NAME), "SUBJ_ID", "SUBJ_VAL");
```

Comment: By the way, this code is working. Just want to know how to add an `AND` where clause. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand... can't you just expand the `o.Type == "4"` with a `&&` operator and refine your filtering there?

Comment: `_odb.SUBJ_MSTR.Where(o => o.TYPE== "4" && o.TYPE=="5")`

Comment: Hi @SimonBelanger It's my first time doing an `AND` in a SelectList, still learning how to `LINQ`. @Div thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `&&` with `WHERE` like this way.

```
ViewBag.Subjects = new SelectList(_odb.SUBJ_MSTR.
                   Where(o => o.TYPE== "4" && o.TYPE=="5").OrderBy(o => o.SUBJ_NAME), "SUBJ_ID", "SUBJ_VAL");
```